# Tool to screenshot a list of local URLs or automatic spider of a website

Tags: open-source, screenshot

I have a localhost (development) website that requires login and I want to automatically take a full page screenshot of several URLs I have. The URLs can be a fixed list I provide or even better if the tool can 'spider' the website automatically. The tool should save all the screenshots in a way easy to create an history of the website along the time and comparison of the same URLs. It has to run on windows in a more of less 'automatic' way.

I'm aware of some tools I can use if I do some programming, I just wanted a tool already ready to use. Open-source would be very nice but a paid app is also a good suggestion if reasonably priced.